# www not working with sub domain based multi tenant asp.net mvc 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service, multi-tenant

I have developed the sub domain based multi tenant application in asp.net mvc 5 and deployed in the azure app service platform. It is working with the following url patterns perfectly.

**t1.abc.com/.../.../...---**

**t2.abc.com/.../.../...---**

But when I try with the following urls

**www.t1.abc.com/.../.../...---**

**www.t2.abc.com/.../.../...---**

It is showing the following 404 error page.

[image]

How it can be solved?

Is it possible to use **Url Rewrite** to solve this issue?

I am trying to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368665/proper-method-to-remove-www-from-address-using-iis-url-rewrite) solution but it does not seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure WebApps support only Wildcard domains as of now as per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-websites-and-wildcard-domains/ and support for double wildcard custom domains is not yet there/

This is actually on the feedback\suggestions list https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/7026845-support-double-wildcard-custom-domains

You might have to add the www custom domains manually in the portal to make this work.

Comment: Is it possible to use Url Rewrite to solve this issue?

Comment: Not really....even for urlrewrite to work the domain name has to be associated with the site first.